# problem with deploying django project on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

i can't deploy my website because of favicon problem (i don't have favicon on my static)

```
2021-03-10T05:27:41.838422+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=sausagepolls.herokuapp.com request_id=81a5685f-9561-4523-bdd0-b276d66f99c3 fwd="156.214.1.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-03-10T05:27:42.124704+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sausagepolls.herokuapp.com request_id=018aa90c-998f-48d4-9cba-1c1473edde29 fwd="156.214.1.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: The error is `No web processes running`. Show your `Procfile`.

Comment: that's it  `web : gunicorn PollProject.wsgi --log-file`

Comment: Start the web process from your Heroku dashboard. Provide the logs of you starting the process.

Comment: Fixed it! ```you just have to save Procfile without the .txt```